# bash shell script fibonacci not showing value 2 after 0 1 1?

Tags: bash, shell, fibonacci

I am writing a bash script for fibonacci which is not printing the value after 0 1 1 .
It is not printing "2" after 0 1 1. 
The code is given below.

```
echo "enter the number"
read n
a=0
b=1
c=0
echo $a
echo $b
while [ $b -le $n ]
do
  c=`expr $a + $b`
  echo $c
  b=`expr $b + 1`
  a=$b
  b=$c
done
```

Answer (score 3):

In bash, do not use the dollar sign on the left hand side of an assignment.

$c=$a+$b

should be

c=$a+$b

but it probably still does not do what you want, try

```
c=$((a+b))
```

instead.

Comment: i tried a simple addition program with this c=$a+$b and it works. So, why do you say that the above code will not work.

Comment: @phpbeginner If you tried it you should have seen that it does *not* work. It does not add the numbers, it creates a string whose content is literally “0+1”. What you can do instead is write `let c=$a+$b` (or what choroba wrote in his answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "enter the number"
read n
a=0
b=1
c=0
while [ $b -le $n ]
do
  c=`expr $a + $b`
  echo $c ' = ' $a ' + '  $b
  a=$b
  b=$c
done
```

Comment: Error:
fib.sh: 8: [: Illegal number: 0+1

Comment: 60 works for me. Are you sure you are using the bash shell? Try echo $SHELL

Comment: Yes $SHELL says /bin/bash

Comment: Well, then I'm not sure what your issue is. Ensure you are using backticks. `expr $a + $b` not 'expr $a + $b'

Comment: Yes I know about the backticks.

Comment: Use `$((a + b))` instead of a `expr` in a sub shell.